# Laravel aws s3 ( Storage::disk('s3' )->put($folderName,$image)); always return false

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AWS S3 to upload images but when I try to upload an image I am getting this error every time:

> InvalidArgumentException
> PHP 8.1.14
> 9.52.0
> Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the GetObject operation: [Key] expected string length to be >= 1, but found string length of 0

This is my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (auth()->user()->can(['add-category'])) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Category::rules(), Category::messages());

        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            try {
                DB::transaction(function () use($request) {
                    $name_en = $request->input('name_en');
                    $name_ar = $request->input('name_ar');
                    $parent_id = $request->input('parent_id');
                    $brand_ids = $request->input('brand_ids');
                    $category_order = $request->input('category_order');
                    $status = $request->input('status');
                    $category = new Category();
                    $category->name_en = $name_en;
                    $category->slug = Str::slug($category->name_en);
                    $category->name_ar = $name_ar;
                    $category->category_order = $category_order;
                    $category->parent_id = $parent_id;
                    $category->status = $status;

                    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                        $uploadFolder = 'category';
                        $image = $request->file('image');

                        $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put($uploadFolder, $image, 'public');
                        dd($path);

                        $category->image = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);
                    }

                    $category->save();

                    if (!empty($brand_ids)) {
                        $category->brands()->attach($brand_ids);
                    }
                });

                notify()->success("Category Added Successfully!");

                return redirect()->route('category.index');
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                dd($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            notify()->error($validator->errors()->first());

            return back();
        }
    }

    abort(401);
}
```

Comment: The error should be on `$category->image = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);`, because you are trying to get the `URL` => `GetObject` operation the error is reporting, if I am not confused, it is saying you did not upload anything because `$path` is either empty or you have a bad path. Share what `$path` is returning please

Comment: thanks for your reply ,, when i print the path it returns false every time, I'm not sure why . it was working fine few days back but now gives this error.

Comment: Yeah, so you have not uploaded anything. Che k why it is failing